# Cannot convert PrivateKey to String

Tags: android, encryption, rsa, private-key, android-keystore

I want to convert an private key to an String so that user can store it in hard state .

i tried to convert the private key  using Base64 but it gives me error stating privateKey.getEncoded() is null

So i tried before Base64 and again i got null .

```
public String newKey() throws
            NoSuchAlgorithmException,
            NoSuchProviderException,
            InvalidAlgorithmParameterException, KeyStoreException, CertificateEncodingException, UnrecoverableEntryException {

        KeyPairGenerator keyPairGenerator = KeyPairGenerator.getInstance(ALGORITHM, KEYSTORE);
        KeyGenParameterSpec keyGenParameterSpec = new KeyGenParameterSpec
                .Builder(alias, KeyProperties.PURPOSE_ENCRYPT | KeyProperties.PURPOSE_DECRYPT)
                .setBlockModes(KeyProperties.BLOCK_MODE_ECB)
                .setEncryptionPaddings(PADDING)
                .build();

        keyPairGenerator.initialize(keyGenParameterSpec);
        PrivateKey key = keyPairGenerator.generateKeyPair().getPrivate();

        KeyStore.PrivateKeyEntry entry = (KeyStore.PrivateKeyEntry) keyStore.getEntry(alias,null);
        String a = privateKeyEntryToString(entry,key);
        //  java.util.Base64.getDecoder().decode(entry)
        //  Log.d("tag",entry);


        Log.d("tag", "done in new Key returning keypublic");
        return a;
       // return keyPairGenerator.generateKeyPair().getPublic();

    }
```

```
    private String privateKeyEntryToString(KeyStore.PrivateKeyEntry privateKeyEntry,PrivateKey key) throws CertificateEncodingException {

 Certificate certificate = privateKeyEntry.getCertificate();
        if (key.getEncoded().length == 0){ // but here we get exception that it is null.
            return "its empty";
        }
        
        

        // Convert PrivateKey and Certificate to String
        String privateKeyString = Base64.encodeToString(key.getEncoded(), Base64.DEFAULT);
        String certificateString = Base64.encodeToString(certificate.getEncoded(), Base64.DEFAULT);

        // Combine both strings with a separator for later use
        return privateKeyString + "-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----\n" + certificateString;
```

Stack trace :

```
FATAL EXCEPTION: main
Process: com.leo.nopasswordforyou, PID: 9525
java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to get length of null array
```

Comment: The Android Keystore protects private keys and will not allow them to be exported from their protected environment.

Comment: @PresidentJamesK.Polk you can get private key during making of it. And this question is not about how to get private key from keystore. the key is parsed differently from Entry .

Comment: I was making the assumption that the Keystore being used was the [Android Keystore](https://developer.android.com/privacy-and-security/keystore). If this is incorrect you will need to provide more code showing where the arguments to your `privateKeyEntryToString()` function come from. You can get a PrivateKey *object* from that keystore, but it contains no sensitive private key information and `getEncoded()` called on it will return `null`.

Comment: @PresidentJamesK.Polk i had edited the original question. and added privateKeyEntryToString function

Comment: And what is the value of `KEYSTORE` in `KeyPairGenerator keyPairGenerator = KeyPairGenerator.getInstance(ALGORITHM, KEYSTORE);`?

Comment: i didn't know what you mean but , after the keyPairGenerator is prompt to generate it stores them in keyStore and returns KeyPair of public and private key in an KeyPair.

Comment: Android contains multiple keystore implementations that all can be used through the same API. One is the `AndroidKeystore` which doesn't allow key export and other implementations just save the key password protected in a file thus you can do what you want with the private key. Therefore we need to know the value of `KEYSTORE`.

Comment: final String KEYSTORE = "AndroidKeyStore"; ,final String ALGORITHM = "RSA";

Comment: Then it is exactly as James assumed. You are using the hardware based store that protects the keys. You don't have to store them anywhere, they are already saved in a secure way, backed by hardware protected security measure. `getEndcoded` will never work for such keys.

Comment: @Robert the thing is i am getting Private key from keyPairGenerator.generateKeyPair() , so does that mean after generating keyPair , it stores them in KeyPair and when prompted to receive , it forwards the keystore's key .  eg : keyPairGenerator.generateKeyPair().getPrivate();

Comment: You haven't been reading what I've been writing.

Comment: so is there any other way (other than keyStore) where i can get the both keys , and later getting keys i can put them in KeyStore. @PresidentJamesK.Polk i am sorry i am not getting what you were saying.

Comment: if someone had other approaches to get the keys , please write answer to it , so that i can mark this question answered. thankyou

Comment: If you want the private key just don't use `AndroidKeystore`. Just search Stackoverflow how TK generate an RSA key in Java without Android. The Java way will also work on Android.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> the thing is i am getting Private key from keyPairGenerator.generateKeyPair() , so does that mean after generating keyPair , it stores them in KeyPair and when prompted to receive, it forwards the keystore's key . eg : `keyPairGenerator.generateKeyPair().getPrivate();`

I think that this is where the misconception lies. The keys are **generated within** the Android key store, they are **not** imported into it. And the Android key store does protect the value of the private key.

If you want to create the keys in software then you can simply try and remove the badly named `KEYSTORE` argument entirely; by default the Android *provider*  won't be used. And yes, this is a bit of a weird API, you can probably not just set it to `null` and remain compatible; you may also have to remove the `NoSuchProviderException` from any catch clause if you do.